# Disable iframe on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using Vimeo to show a background video in an iframe and I want this disabled and replaced by an image on mobile devices. Normally I'd do this type of thing by hosting the video and using `<video><source></video>` but that's not possible in this case. I can't really find much in the way of best practice approach to achieving this and all I can think of is something like this.

```
if($(window).width() < 768) {
 // .remove() iframe and display image
}
```

There must be a better method, no? One that prevents the video being loaded initially.

Comment: You could use a css `display: none;` with media query in order to do that, no ?

Comment: Depends on how you expect this to work. By the time you try to remove iframe it will already have started loading since you can't query an element before it exists

Comment: I could but I think that the video will still be loaded over the network

Comment: Would be better to think the opposite approach. Always load image and on larger screens convert to iframe on page load and on smaller screens convert when user clicks on image

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting approach @charlietfl

Comment: Like said, you can just display a thumbnail, then check if it is a mobile or desktop and if it is a mobile, don't retrieve the video.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea but in my case it might not work. The video displayed can be edited by the client so I'm not sure how I'd account for this given the suggested solution. My thinking (which cold be wrong) is that the iframe first has to appear in the DOM and it's then disabled when required.